# Who is the 4th Sentinel of Time whose statue is broken in the Citadel at the End of Time?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, loki-2021

In *Loki* episode 6, as Loki and Sylvie go deep into the castle, they are in a room with three standing statues (dubbed "Sentinels of Time" by production designer Kasra Farahani) and one that's been demolished.

Whose statue is that?

[image: Image of the three standing statues and one broken]

Comment: The theory appears to be it is of He Who Remains, or a variant of. I don't think there's any information on this yet. That goes for the other statues as well.

Answer (score 5):

Borrowing from comics lore, and [the Screen Rant video on easter eggs in the episode](https://youtu.be/k8GgcLcUxrk?t=464), that may be a reference to [The Oracle of Siwa](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Oracle_of_Siwa_(Earth-616)), the fourth [Time Keeper](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Time-Keepers#History) created by He Who Remains, who rebelled and was exiled to ancient Egypt. In this case, since the Time Keepers were all animatronics, odds are there was no actual Ramades, but He Who Remains may have created his own mythology regarding the Time Keepers that included this fourth, exiled, member to be used if he needed to provide further backstory to the Time Keepers to members of the TVA. Or, simply, because he's very bored and enjoys making his stories.